# RNCryptor Sign with OpenSSL and private key

Tags: openssl, public-key-encryption, sign, pem, rncryptor

i use RNCryptor in my iOS project.

i have a openssl .pem (private key) file. and only that file.

i need to use that file to encript / sign a string.

does anybody know how the code could look like to do that?

Comment: The private key is not used to encrypt data but decrypt. You need a public key to encrypt.

Comment: Use OpenSSL to generate key pair.

Comment: you can and have to encrypt and decript with both public and private key. one does reversal of other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RNCryptor is a format and library for managing AES symmetrical encryption. What you're describing is very likely RSA asymmetrical encryption (public/private key encryption). They're not compatible.

Comment: @Rob are there any libraries that do asymmetrical encryption, like RNCryptor does symmetrical?

Comment: @Ryan please see my Answer here for [RSA Encription with no external libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608727/encrypt-or-sign-string-with-public-key-in-ios-with-objective-c). Maybe that helps.